# Filter ElasticSearch results by Mongo _id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, elasticsearch, tire

I'm currently using Mongoid/MongoDB for my database with Tire/ElasticSearch. I want to filter my results based on an array of `_id`'s. Here is some pseudo-code similar to what I'm attempting:

```
search = Tire::Search::Search.new()
search.filter :terms, :_id => [array_of_ids]
```

When I swap out the `:_id` attribute and attempt to use another indexed attribute, it works fine. However, with `:_id`, it returns no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you're not allowed to filter by `:_id` or `:id`. Whether this is Tire specific or ElasticSearch specific, I'm unsure.

In my Tire custom mapping, I've gone ahead and added a duplicate field as sort of an alias. More psuedo-code:

```
tire.mapping do
  indexes :id,         :index    => :not_analyzed
  indexes :content_id, :analyzer => :keyword,
                       :as       => "_id"
  ...
end
```

The important part being `indexes :content_id, :as => "_id"`. From that point, I filtered using `:content_id`.

Comment: Please try the http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/ids-filter.html filter.